# tools.jar not packaged into the maven package. Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javadoc/Main

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, noclassdeffounderror, umlgraph

I have created a maven project which needs tools.jar to be included. I have added the jar into the lib folder and included the following in the pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}\src\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

When have also added the following plugin to create executable jar for the project.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>umlparser.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I have built the jar using "mvn clean package assembly:single"
This has created an executable jar file with name myproject-jar-with-dependencies.

But when I am trying to run the jar file with java -jar it is unable to get the tools.jar. I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javadoc/Main
        at org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraph.main(UmlGraph.java:70)
        at umlparser.Main.main(Main.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

But when I am exporting it as runnable jar from eclipse it is working as expected. 
What is the issue with the maven package? Am I missing something here?

**EDIT**

I have tried to import the tools.jar dependency from the java_home instead of project path.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0_241</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

Still I am getting the same issue.

Note: The tools.jar is not used in my program. It is being used by one of the jars that I have included - "UMLGraph.jar".

Answer (score 1):

The `com.sun:tools` dependency which you have added has a `system` scope. Dependencies with `provided` and `system` scopes will not be includes in such packaged artifacts.

Specifically in this case, you should also actually ***not*** be doing so, because this jar comes as part of your JDK. The users of your jar will have a JDK/JRE to run the code and if you include `tools` jar you will most-likely be causing a conflict with their JDK/JRE and you really don't want to be doing that.

This being said, you could probably try using `dependencySet` with a `scope` of `system`, but I would really not advise this (even if it does the trick).

I'm assuming that on the system where you're running this jar, you simply don't have the JDK on your `PATH` and you have just the JRE instead. If you fix this, you should not have to do any of this unconventional hacking around.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am running this on my local and it has JDK installed. The Java_Home path is also set in the environment variables correctly to JDK path. Even when I don't include the tools.jar in the dependencies I am getting the same issue. 
I have tried to include it from java_home but it didn't work out as well.


`<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
   <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.0_241</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Also the tools.jar is not used in my program. It is being used by one of the jars that I have included - "UMLGraph.jar".